# Automatically change layout depending on keyboard being used

Tags: linux, keyboard, xorg, keyboard-layout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Separate keyboard for shortcuts on linux (two keyboards,two layouts)](https://superuser.com/questions/351936/separate-keyboard-for-shortcuts-on-linux-two-keyboards-two-layouts)

I have a laptop with a US layout and an external keyboard with a Spanish layout. Is it possible to detect from which keyboard the last keypress came so I can change the layout accordingly? It could be a simple script using setxkbmap that runs after logging in.

edit: [Separate keyboard for shortcuts on linux (two keyboards,two layouts)](https://superuser.com/questions/351936/separate-keyboard-for-shortcuts-on-linux-two-keyboards-two-layouts) works perfectly.

Comment: It certainly seems possible; `setxkbmap` applies to all currently connected keyboards, and plugging in a new one (e.g. USB) on xorg.conf-less Xorg 7.6 gives me default US layout on the external one.

Comment: @JoeyAdams I did't know that site existed, sorry, is there a way I can move it myself?

Answer (score 0):

Each keyboard can already have its own independent layout. Setting it via HAL (on systems that still have it) works, and the keyboard will acquire the assigned layout on plug/start, *provided no other program (e.g. GNOME's keyboard settings plugin) overrides it.*

Comment: I added some rules to HAL's preferences which seem to be sticking (one keyboard shows input.xkb.layout = 'es' when inspected with hal-device, and the other shows 'en' with variant 'alt-intl'. But the main layout I set when I first installed Debian (en_us) seems to be sticking in the console as well as in X. Any hints?